# How can I get the output and test the dig command?

Tags: shell

when we type " dig +short www.example.com " command 
we get something like that:

```
www.example.com.
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
```

I want to get the first address and test it if it is what I want to (192.168.1.1)

How can I get the output of this command, especially the second line by using shell script ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this will do:

```
$ dig +short www.google.com | head -1
74.125.225.113
```

But be careful because most servers that have multiple IP addresses will do some form of round robin at the DNS level so the list is typically rotating every time you run the `dig` command:

```
$ dig +short www.google.com
74.125.225.116
74.125.225.112
74.125.225.113
74.125.225.114
74.125.225.115

$ dig +short www.google.com
74.125.225.115
74.125.225.116
74.125.225.112
74.125.225.113
74.125.225.114

$ dig +short www.google.com 
74.125.225.114
74.125.225.115
74.125.225.116
74.125.225.112
74.125.225.113
```

Notice how the IPs move around from query to query? This is done to balance the load across those servers.

#### Capturing the IP into a variable

The following command will capture the output of the IP address and put it into a shell variable.

```
$ IP=$(dig +short www.google.com | head -1)
```

You can confirm this like so:

```
$ echo $IP
74.125.225.114
```

Comment: but how can I put it in a variable

Comment: @user2683768 - see updates.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```
dig +short  www.example.com | sed -n '2{p;q}'
```

`-n` prevents sed from printing its input by default. `2` causes it to execute `p;q` on line number 2. `p` stands for print and `q` for quit

Comment: could you explain it to me in short @1_CR

Comment: This prints the last line, no? `echo -e "hi1\nhi2"| sed -n '2{p;q}'` gives me `hi2`.

Comment: @slm thanks for the edit. Explanation added.

Comment: I think if you change it from a 2 to a 1 you'll get the first line.

Comment: @slm, good point, now that you mention it. Not an expert at `dig` but would you know why it reports the website name for `www.bbc.co.uk` in its output but not so for `www.google.com`

Comment: If you take the `+short` option off you can see why. There's an extra definition in their DNS definition that defines this: `www.bbc.co.uk.  268 IN CNAME www.bbc.net.uk.`. Not sure why they have this. It seems redundant to me.

Comment: @slm, thanks. Another day lived, another thing learned

Comment: Yes, it's scary how much we don't know, isn't it.